# How to access array values in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This method i am using for storing currentTime in database using ajax call and its working

```
public function saveTime(Request $request, $lession_id){

$user = Auth::user();
if($user === null){
    return response()->json(['message' => 'User not authenticated', 404]);
}

$video = \App\Lession::where('id',$lession_id)->first();

$lesson_id = $request->lession_id;
$progress = $request->time;
//save them somewhere


$watch_history = $user->watch_history;
$watch_history_array = array();
if ($watch_history == '') {
  array_push($watch_history_array, array('lession_id' => $lesson_id, 'progress' => $progress));
} else {
  $founder = false;
  $watch_history_array = json_decode($watch_history, true);
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($watch_history_array); $i++) {
    $watch_history_for_each_lesson = $watch_history_array[$i];
    if ($watch_history_for_each_lesson['lession_id'] == $lesson_id) {
      $watch_history_for_each_lesson['progress'] = $progress;
      $watch_history_array[$i]['progress'] = $progress;
      $founder = true;
    }
  }
  if (!$founder) {
  array_push($watch_history_array, array('lession_id' => $lesson_id, 'progress' => $progress));
  }
}

$data['watch_history'] = json_encode($watch_history_array);

$check = User::where('id',$user->id)->update(['watch_history' => $watch_history_array]);

  return response()->json(['message' => 'Time saved', 200]);//send http response as json back to the ajax call

 }
```

But when I use this another method to get the time back for playback it's getting the array inside an array

```
public function getTime(Request $request, $lession_id){
$user = Auth::user();
if($user === null){
    return response()->json(['message' => 'User not authenticated', 403]);
}
$user_video = User::where('id',$user->id)->first();
$array = $user_video->watch_history;

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  echo $check;
}  
 }
```

My current Output in a database is as follows
**[{"lession_id":"157","progress":"71.449464"},{"lession_id":"156","progress":"92.113123"}]**

So help me to get the values out of that for each lession id

Comment: I'm not sure why did you tag this as javascript/mysql/ajax?

Comment: `json_decode()` is your problem solver. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php or *Cast* in `User Model`.
`Protected $casts = ['watch_history' => 'array']`

Comment: You have 7 questions that is posted recently, no answers and general low answer rate. Your code is fairly messy and not that readable. If you want better answers and more help, please respect stackoverflow questions. and if people try to help you respect them by interacting with them and accepting answers if they help you.